# Close JMS session and connection after message received

Tags: java, jms

I have a stateful session bean where I send and receive JMS messages. All the connection setup is handled manually, so the bean is holding instances of javax.jms.connection and javax.jms.session. The bean also implements MessageListener to be able receive messages.

Now, when I send a message, I create a temporary queue with session.createTemporaryQueue(). I set the message.setJMSReplyTo() to this same temporary queue, and at last creates a consumer of this queue and sets the MessageListener to the same stateful session bean that all this is implemented  in.

I am abel to receive the message to the onMessage() method. However, I want to close the session and connection as soon as the message has been received, and this is apparently not allowed in the onMessage() method.

**So the question is:**
How can I close the session and connection once the message has been received? I must handle the connection setup manually and can not use a MDB.

**Note that:**
This is executed in the Java EE environment (GlassFish 4.0)

EDIT:

```
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import com.sun.messaging.ConnectionConfiguration;
import com.sun.messaging.QueueConnectionFactory;

@LocalBean
@Stateful
public class OpenMqClient implements MessageListener{
    private Connection connection;
    private Session session;
    private MessageConsumer responseConsumer;

    public OpenMqClient(){}

    public void sendMessage(String messageContent, String jmsBrokerUri, String queueName) {
        try{
            String host = System.getProperty("foo", jmsBrokerUri);
            QueueConnectionFactory cf = new QueueConnectionFactory();
            cf.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList, host);
            connection = null;
            session = null;

            //Setup connection
            connection = cf.createConnection();
            connection.start();
            session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            //Setup queue and producer
            Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);


            //Reply destination
            Queue responseQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
            responseConsumer = session.createConsumer(responseQueue);
            responseConsumer.setMessageListener(this);

            //Create message
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
            textMessage.setJMSReplyTo(responseQueue);
            textMessage.setJMSCorrelationID("test0101");
            textMessage.setText(messageContent);

            producer.send(textMessage);
            System.out.println("Message sent");
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("JMSException in Sender");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
        //On this event I want to close the session and connection, but it's not permitted
    }

}
```

Comment: How is the session created? what is the transactional context?

Comment: Opening/closing sessions and connections is an expensive operation, and I would avoid that if you need any kind of performance. Having said that, your best bet is probably to create a new Runnable that takes in your session and connection and spawn a new thread that will close your session and connection in the background - you can even add a time delay so that the connection isn't closed until your onMesage is likely to have finished

Comment: How about creating session and connection once. (for example in @PostConstruct) and then destroying it once ( using @PreDestroy) of the session bean?

Comment: @ringbearer : It is a solution, but it's not very effective since a response is almost always received very quick. However, some responses might take longer time, hence I can not use timeouts. If many users are sending messages, there will be a lot of open sessions that are not used (until the session beans is destroyed).

Comment: Then you will have to stick with what @Matt has suggested. Try running a closer thread from onMessage()

Comment: @Matt : Correct me if I'm wrong, but creating and handling new threads manually in the Java EE environment is more or less tabu and should be handled by the container. I can't use time delays or timeouts to close the session, because the response might take very long time and MUST be taken care of.

Comment: @Humz what  if you initialize the connection to null and then adding a finally block to your try that does {if (conn != null) {conn.close();} Will this cover your scenario ?

Comment: @Humz you were right until Java ee 7 : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html

Comment: @Humz do you want to close the connection after you send the message, or after you receive the message? My understanding is that your flow is like this: 1) open connection 2) send message 3) wait for response 4) close connection... In which case, you don't need a timer in your thread at all. Just spawn the thread to kill the connection - the "response might take very long time" period will happen in between send and receive, once you have received, you don't need it anymore

Comment: Here https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ShouldICacheJMSConnectionsAndJMSSessions cache JMS connections/sessions recomendation from JBoss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, this is how I would do it (note I haven't tested or added much error handling to this code).

1. Make the connection static - you can (probably should) reuse the same connection for all your beans unless you have a specific reason not to
2. Close the session in a new thread

   ```
   public class OpenMqClient implements MessageListener {

       private static Connection connection;
       private static final String mutex = "mutex"; 
       private Session session;
       private MessageConsumer responseConsumer;

       public OpenMqClient() {
           if(connection == null) {
               synchronized(mutex) {
                   if(connection == null) {
                       String host = System.getProperty("foo", jmsBrokerUri);
                       QueueConnectionFactory cf = new QueueConnectionFactory();
                       cf.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList, host);

                       // Setup connection
                       connection = cf.createConnection();
                       connection.start();
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       public void sendMessage(String messageContent, String jmsBrokerUri, String queueName) {
           try {
               session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

               // Setup queue and producer
               Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
               MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

               // Reply destination
               Queue responseQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
               responseConsumer = session.createConsumer(responseQueue);
               responseConsumer.setMessageListener(this);

               // Create message
               TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
               textMessage.setJMSReplyTo(responseQueue);
               textMessage.setJMSCorrelationID("test0101");
               textMessage.setText(messageContent);

               producer.send(textMessage);
               System.out.println("Message sent");
           } catch (JMSException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               System.out.println("JMSException in Sender");
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
           // do stuff
           new Thread(
               new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       if(session != null)
                           try {
                               session.close();
                           } catch (JMSException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }               
                   }
               }
           ).start();
       }
   }
   ```